# MySQL: Limit on certain field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

Say I have a table with field like this:

```
ID       Name         Parent_ID
1       Maxim         1
2       Bruce         1
3       Jonas         3
4       Steve         4
5       Chloe         4
6       Paul          4
7       Frank         7
8       Paula         8
9       Martin        9
10      Hank          9
```

And I want to get a query with only top 3 different parent Ids, which would have Parent_ID of 1, 3, and 4 like below:

```
ID     Name         Parent_ID
1       Maxim         1
2       Bruce         1
3       Jonas         3
4       Steve         4
5       Chloe         4
6       Paul          4
```

How can I get this using MySQL. Can I use the LIMIT function. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn the use IN clause in MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will help you

```
select t1.* from table1 as t1
inner join
(select distinct Parent_ID from table1 order by Parent_ID limit 3) as t2
on t1.Parent_ID = t2.Parent_ID
```

Comment: i got this error when i run the query: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename
-> WHERE parent_id IN ( 1,3,4 );
```

Comment: may be i'm not making myself too clear. What I want actually is to limit the result like in the LIMIT clause, so I can get the result per page.